# How can I move every GameObject at the same time?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I'm creating a grid-based rhythm game, inspired by *Crypt of the Necrodancer*.
For this I have to move the Player, as well as the Enemys (Chickens in my case), at the **exact** same time.

I have created a GameLogic Script in which a Timer is counting down to zero:

```
public class GameLogic : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float maxTime = 0.5f;
    public float timeLeft;

    public bool move;

    void Start()
    {

        timeLeft = maxTime;
    }

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        //Universal Timer
        timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;

        if(timeLeft <= 0)
        {
            move = true;
            UpdateTime();
        }


    }

    public void UpdateTime()
    {
        timeLeft = maxTime;
        move = false;

    }
```

Now I reference this Timer in the player script:

```
 GameLogic gameLogic;

    Vector3 up = Vector3.zero,
    right = new Vector3(0, 90, 0),
    down = new Vector3(0, 180, 0),
    left = new Vector3(0, 270, 0),
    currentDirection = Vector3.zero;

    Vector3 nextPos, destination, direction;

    float speed = 5;
    float rayLength = 1f;
    //float timeLeft;
    //public float maxTime = 1;



    bool canMove = true;
    //bool movedToNext;
    bool bouncedOff;


    void Start()
    {
        GameObject g = GameObject.Find("Game Logic");
        gameLogic = g.GetComponent<GameLogic>();

        currentDirection = up;
        nextPos = Vector3.forward;
        destination = transform.position;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        BeatMovement();
        Move();

    }

    void BeatMovement()
    {
        //timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;

        if (gameLogic.move)
        {
            canMove = true;
            bouncedOff = false;

            //gameLogic.move = false;

        }
        else { canMove = false; }
    }

    void Move()
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, destination, speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            nextPos = Vector3.forward;
            currentDirection = up;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow))
        {
            nextPos = Vector3.back;
            currentDirection = down;

        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            nextPos = Vector3.right;
            currentDirection = right;

        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            nextPos = Vector3.left;
            currentDirection = left;

        }


        if (Vector3.Distance(destination, transform.position) <= 0.000001f)
        {
            transform.localEulerAngles = currentDirection;

            if(canMove)
            {
                if(Valid())
                {
                    destination = transform.position + nextPos;
                    direction = nextPos;

                }
                else
                {
                    if(currentDirection == up && bouncedOff == false)
                    {
                        nextPos = Vector3.back;
                        currentDirection = down;
                        bouncedOff = true;

                    }
                    if (currentDirection == down && bouncedOff == false)
                    {
                        nextPos = Vector3.forward;
                        currentDirection = up;
                        bouncedOff = true;
                    }

                    if (currentDirection == left && bouncedOff == false)
                    {
                        nextPos = Vector3.right;
                        currentDirection = right;
                        bouncedOff = true;
                    }

                    if (currentDirection == right && bouncedOff == false)
                    {
                        nextPos = Vector3.left;
                        currentDirection = left;
                        bouncedOff = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //checks if there is an obstacle in the destinationPosition the Player wants to move
    bool Valid()
    {
        Ray myRay = new Ray(transform.position + new Vector3(0, 0.25f, 0), transform.forward);
        RaycastHit hit;

        Debug.DrawRay(myRay.origin, myRay.direction, Color.red);

        if(Physics.Raycast(myRay, out hit, rayLength))
        {
            if(hit.collider.tag == "Obstacle")
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        //if the raycast doesnt hit anything the movement is valid (true) 
        return true;
    }
}
```

This seems to work. But as soon as there is an other GameObject using this Timer, things get complicated. Neither of the GameObjects will move. I think it's because the timer won't reach zero anymore, and gets Updated to soon. I tried to Update the time in the player or ChickeScripts but that will result in one of them not being able to move. I can see the Problem I just don't know how to fix it.

Here is the Code of the Chicken using a PathFollower Script:

```
public class PathFollower : MonoBehaviour
{
    Node[] pathNode;
    public GameObject player;

    Vector3 CurrentPositionHolder;
    int CurrentNode;


    GameLogic gamelogic;

    void Start()
    {
        GameObject g = GameObject.Find("Game Logic");

        pathNode = GetComponentsInChildren<Node>();
        gamelogic = g.GetComponent<GameLogic>();

        CheckNode();

    }

    void CheckNode()
    {
        //tells me on which position the next Node is
        CurrentPositionHolder = pathNode[CurrentNode].transform.position;
    }

    void Update()
    {   
        if (gamelogic.move)
        {
            Movement();
        }
    }

    void Movement()
    {

        //moves player to the next position
        if (player.transform.position != CurrentPositionHolder)
        {
            player.transform.position = CurrentPositionHolder;
              Debug.Log("moves");

        }
        else
        //if player is on the position u want him to be then set the next node 
        {
            if (CurrentNode < pathNode.Length - 1)
            {
                CurrentNode++;
                CheckNode();

            }
        }

        if (CurrentNode == pathNode.Length -1)
        {
            CurrentNode = 0;
            CheckNode();

        }
    }
}
```

I'm happy about any suggestions! Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you basically have here, is a turnbased game. Crypt of the Necrodancer is a roguelike and being turnbased was one important property of game Rogue.

Usually games are split into "GameTicks" called units. A "realtime" game, just has a very high rate GameTicks (30-60 per second) that does not wait for user input to finish turns. Usually it is more about limiting the GameTicks to a upper bound and making sure you do not slow up drawing. The gameticks should always be counted and processed in Update, never the Drawcode.

Now the thing is, that nowadays the ticks do *more* then just counting the turns. There is other stuff like some parts of animations they need to time. Or interpreting user input not related to play (menu). Without any knowledge of it I can say, that Unity will provide a Game Tick counter. Either in a overload of Update as parameter, or as a class field.

So you got two options:

1. Use the tick counting for the game turns. But keep keep input processing out of it. Basically only the move part of Update is under Tick limitation/counting
2. Limit the tick counting as usual, but have the Turns be a seperate counter. One you advance as a subpart of the Update code under gameticks.
3. There might be Unity support for this particular case. If it is, usually use that one.